# Почему не работает код цикла while True?

Tags: python

Писал программу для камень ножницы бумага и т.д
Сначала все работало прекрасно, а потом перестал выполнять все, что находится в цикле while True
код:

```
import random
bot = 0
you = 0
print('''Привет!Это игра Камень Ножницы Бумага!
Но это расширенная версия) тут есть счёт.
Когда либо у тебя либо у бота набирается 11 очков, то партия заканчивается, и начинается новая.
Всего играем до 2 выигрышных партий.
Нажми Enter чтобы начать.
Удачи!''')
input()
while True:
 if you == 11:
        print('Партия закончилась в твою пользу!')
        partyou += 1
 elif partyou == 2:
        print('Ты выиграл обе партии!')
 if bot == 11:
        print('Партия закончлась в пользу бота!')
        partbot += 1
 elif partbot == 2:
        print('Ты проиграл обе партии!')
 a = ['Камень','Ножницы','Бумага','Карандаш','Огонь','Вода','Бутылка лимонада','Железная рука']
 b = input('Выбери. Камень Ножницы Бумага Карандаш Огонь Вода и Бутылка лимонада и Железная рука: ')
 с = (random.choice(a))
 rock = 'Камень'
 nozj = 'Ножницы'
 paper = 'Бумага'
 pencil = 'Карандаш'
 fire = 'Огонь'
 water = 'Вода'
 butilka = 'Бутылка лимонада'
 iron = 'Железная рука'
 win = 'Ты выиграл!'
 lose = 'Ты проиграл!'
 draw = 'Ничья!' 
 partyou = 0
 partbot = 0
 if b == 'Обновить':
      bot = bot-bot
      you = you-you
 print(f'Счёт: {you}:{bot}')
 continue
 print(f'Твой выбор:{b}, выбор бота:{c}')
    #Счёт Очки Партии
    #Победа, проигрыш или ничья? А также счёт
    #Ничья
 if c == b:
        print(draw)
 elif c == water and b == butilka:
        print(draw)
 elif c == butilka and b == water:
        print(draw)
 else:
        #Камень
        if c == rock and b == nozj:
            print(lose)
            bot = bot+1
        elif c == rock and b == paper:
            print(win)
            you = you+1
        elif c == rock and b == pencil:
            print(lose)
            bot = bot+1
        elif c == rock and b == fire:
            print(win)
            you = you+1
        elif c == rock and b == water:
            print(win)
            you = you+1
        elif c == rock and b == butilka:
            print(lose)
            bot = bot+1
        elif c == rock and b == iron:
            print(lose)
            bot = bot+1
        else:
            #Ножницы
            if c == nozj and b == rock:
                print(win)
                you = you+1
            elif c == nozj and b == paper:
                print(lose)
                bot = bot+1
            elif c == nozj and b == pencil:
                print(lose)
                bot = bot+1
            elif c == nozj and b == fire:
                print(win)
                you = you+1
            elif c == nozj and b == water:
                print(win)
                you = you+1
            elif c == nozj and b == butilka:
                print(lose)
                bot = bot+1
            elif c == nozj and b == iron:
                print(win)
                you+1
            else:
                #Бумага
                if c == paper and b == rock:
                    print(lose)
                    bot = bot+1
                elif c == paper and b == nozj:
                    print(win)
                    you = you+1
                elif c == paper and b == pencil:
                    print(win)
                    you = you+1
                elif c == paper and b == fire:
                    print(win)
                    you = you+1
                elif c == paper and b == water:
                    print(win)
                    you = you+1
                elif c == paper and b == butilka:
                    print(win)
                    you = you+1
                elif c == paper and b == iron:
                    print(win)
                    you = you+1
                else:
                    #Карандаш
                    if c == pencil and b == rock:
                        print(win)
                        you = you+1
                    elif c == pencil and b == nozj:
                        print(win)
                        you = you+1
                    elif c == pencil and b == paper:
                        print(lose)
                        bot = bot+1
                    elif c == pencil and b == fire:
                        print(win)
                        you = you+1
                    elif c == pencil and b == water:
                        print(lose)
                        bot = bot+1
                    elif c == pencil and b == butilka:
                        print(lose)
                        bot = bot+1
                    elif c == pencil and b == iron:
                        print(win)
                        you = you+1
                    else:
                        #Огонь
                        if c == fire and b == rock:
                            print(lose)
                            bot = bot+1
                        elif c == fire and b == nozj:
                            print(lose)
                            bot = bot+1
                        elif c == fire and b == paper:
                            print(lose)
                            bot = bot+1
                        elif c == fire and b == pencil:
                            print(lose)
                            bot = bot+1
                        elif c == fire and b == water:
                            print(win)
                            you = you+1
                        elif c == fire and b == butilka:
                            print(win)
                            you = you+1
                        elif c == fire and b == iron:
                            print(lose)
                            bot = bot+1
                        else:
                            #Вода
                            if c == water and b == rock:
                                print(lose)
                                bot = bot+1
                            elif c == water and b == nozj:
                                print(lose)
                                bot = bot+1
                            elif c == water and b == paper:
                                print(lose)
                                bot = bot+1
                            elif c == water and b == pencil:
                                print(win)
                                you = you+1
                            elif c == water and b == fire:
                                print(lose)
                                bot = bot+1
                            elif c == water and b == iron:
                                print(lose)
                                bot = bot+1
                            else:
                                #Бутылка лимонада
                                if c == butilka and b == rock:
                                    print(win)
                                    you = you+1
                                elif c == butilka and b == nozj:
                                    print(win)
                                    you = you+1
                                elif c == butilka and b == paper:
                                    print(lose)
                                    bot = bot+1
                                elif c == butilka and b == pencil:
                                    print(win)
                                    you = you+1
                                elif c == butilka and b == fire:
                                    print(lose)
                                    bot = bot+1
                                elif c == butilka and b == iron:
                                    print(lose)
                                    bot = bot+1
                                else:
                                    #Железная рука
                                    if c == iron and b == rock:
                                        print(win)
                                        you = you+1
                                    elif c == iron and b == nozj:
                                        print(lose)
                                        bot = bot+1
                                    elif c == iron and b == paper:
                                        print(lose)
                                        bot = bot+1
                                    elif c == iron and b == pencil:
                                        print(lose)
                                        bot = bot+1
                                    elif c == iron and b == fire:
                                        print(win)
                                        you = you+1
                                    elif c == iron and b == water:
                                        print(win)
                                        you = you+1
                                    elif c == iron and b == butilka:
                                        print(win)
                                        you = you+1
 print(f'''Счёт: {you}:{bot}  
Счёт партий: {partyou}:{partbot}''') #Счёт
 continue
input()
```

Comment: Да вроде нет, но continue было не там, исправил, но проблема осталась

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте перед циклом.

```
partyou = 0
partbot = 0
```

Это решит ошибку из-за которой программа закрывается.
Судя по коду для вас сейчас будет гораздо лучше научиться основам, а потом писать свои игры. Возможно вы пишите на телефоне, но все же посторайтесь делать отступы ровнее и одинаковее.

Comment: Да! Спасибо! Но, я только учусь питону, пишу на ноутбуке, но за совет спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Ещё, я думаю, будет не лишнем перейти от конструкций if/elif/else к match/case

https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/tsikly-upravlenie-vetvleniem-python/konstruktsija-match-case/